# JS dose not work in Monaca (Onsen-ui)

Tags: javascript, html, onsen-ui, monaca

I try to change the text when the button is click but i thing i miss something 
im new in using onsen-ui and read about this problem so i came up that my JS NOT work in mobile >>
please if any one can help !!

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsen-css-components.css">
<script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
<script>
  ons.bootstrap();
 
</script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
}
</script>
<body>
 <h1>JavaScript in Head</h1>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-navigator>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to add `<ons-navigator>` and `<ons-page>` tags. If you noticed, they are closed but never opened.

Here if the fixed code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsen-css-components.css">
<script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
<script>
  ons.bootstrap();
</script>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
  }
</script>

<body>
  <ons-navigator>
    <ons-page>
      <h1>JavaScript in Head</h1>

      <p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

      <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-navigator>
</body>
```